# Is Metal a good framework to use for multiple video rendering?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, metal

I am building an iOS application that will render 4 separate video camera feeds (video frame buffers) on the screen simultaneously. (Something like the multi security cam monitors)
To achieve this, one possible solution is I map each video source to a different view within my view controller and directly render each buffer onto the view using CALayer and adding it as a sublayer to the view. Basically a one to one mapping of video source to view.

My question is, does the metal framework provide some kind of optimization or performance gain for my scenario? I am new to Metal and any advice is appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: If you can get a `CVPixelBufferRef` for each frame of the feeds, you could generate a Metal texture pretty efficiently with a `CVMetalTextureCache`, and then draw it onto a quad with Metal. Before all of that, though, have you tried implementing this with a higher level API like `AVPlayerLayer`?

Comment: Thanks warrenm, I haven't considered AVPlayer, thinking that it is more suited for playback, while I have realtime live feed (no play,pause rewind). I will look into CVPixelBufferRef to improve performance.

Comment: I would suggest that you use OpenGL via GLKit and render the video such that the video is delivered as YUV buffers as opposed to BGRA data. There are hardware optimizations around blitting the YUV buffer if you pass it directly into OpenGL as Y and UV textures.

Comment: There's definitely a performance gain by using Metal, in general—particularly, for multiple video feeds. If the same instructions are being used for each video, then you can reuse the same set of instructions four times.

That's much different than OpenGL, and these videos explain exactly why:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/602/
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/603/
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/604/
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/605/

Comment: Since you are writing a custom filter I guess you already have found sucess with what I am stuck at. I am trying to apply a simple vignette filter to a live camera feed using metal. The results are pretty slow and laggy, please check this if you can tell me what is missing:https://stackoverflow.com/q/53898780/1364053